# wss3.0 to moss 2007 migration

Tags: sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

i was creating a website in wss 3.0. now i have a licensed moss version. i would like to tranfer all the content from wss to my newly installed moss. i came accross the export/import command and tried it. the export worked fine. the import gives me the following error:

the export command from wss 3.0 was:

```
stsadm -o export -url http://priya -filename default.aspx -includeusersecurity -update version 4
```

the import command to shift the entire content to moss 2007 was:

```
stsadm -o import -url http://priya:23795 -filename default.aspx -includesecurity -ipdateversions 2
```

the error was:

```
Fatal Error: cannot import site. the exported site is based on the template STS#0 but the destination site is ased on the template CENTRALADMIN#0. You can import sites only into sites that ar based on the same template as the exported site.
```

Comment: Are you trying to import site to central admin? :)

Comment: no im trying to shift my entire website to moss. what i want is that i want to shift the entire content i.e. whatever stuff i have created as a part of the website i want to shift it to moss without having to start afresh..

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that, you are trying to import a Team Site to Central Amin Site (?)

I see that you are new to SP. Check this post [Database Migration from WSS 2.0 to MOSS 2007](http://geekswithblogs.net/RogueCoder/archive/2007/05/08/112343.aspx) for some detailed information about how to migrate.

Comment: yes, i m fairly new to sp. the article you mentioned sems to provide information on wss 2.0 to moss 2007.but i would like to shift my website from wss3.0 to mos 2007.could you please shed some light on this?

Comment: Here  you go!! http://joeblog.homnick.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=db4a6966-2b11-448d-a4ba-1550e74c89ba&ID=30 Another google search :)

Comment: this was exactly what i did before i landed on the error. from the same post mentioned above.. :)

Comment: i have created my wbsite using sharepoint designer. so i want these files t be moved to the path that leads to the moss server instead of the older path which used wss3.0.

Comment: Oops.. Okay Sorry! http://priya:23795  is this the central admi site? What template did you use for this new site?

Comment: Are you sure because the error says you are trying to import to a site which uses CENTRALADMIN#0 template and not a team site template. Also how come you have the same address for both wss and moss (priya and priya:23795) ?

Comment: so does it mean that the number given there does not make a difference? i was told that beforre importinf i should create a blank site and import my website to this so that the template problem does not arise. but how do i know whether the site is being created in wss or moss? n how should i go about the whole importing business? i m totally confused!

Comment: hmm!!! looks like lot of confusion here! Are you have WSS and MOSS in the same server? AFAIK You cant have both WSS and MOSS in the same server. I see that you are taking a backup from http://priya .. but you are also importing it to http://priya but in a different port. So looks like its same machine.

Comment: Woah!! Okay... Did you install MOSS?? .. You said you have installed MOSS. WSS and MOSS should be in different servers. Take backup from WSS server. Copy the file to the MOSS server and import.

Comment: How did you install WSS and MOSS in the same machine?

Comment: wss was already installed. i jus installed moss ovr it and it did not ask me to uninstall wss or anything.. so i guess my wss is still alive and well..

Comment: Well!! First WSS and MOSS do not co-exist in the same machine. They cannot be installed together AFAIK. I am not sure whether you have upgraded WSS. You have the backup file now. Did you crdate a new site http://priya:23795 ?? What do you get when you browse priya:23795 ?

Comment: i get the same page that i used to get earlier. no noticeable difference.

Comment: i have a backup file called backup.cmp now.

Comment: What you did is correct but you new site is not Team Site! That is the issue here. Can't really answer without knowing more details like.. how does MOSS and WSS exist together? What is your CA address? Looks like the "team site" you call in MOSS is not really a team site.

Comment: not sure whether you have checke this : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/back-up-restore-or-move-a-sharepoint-site-HA010069939.aspx  .. "i get the same page that i used to get earlier. no noticeable difference." What page?? Team site page?